# Concerning publication my master's thesis

Tags: thesis, plagiarism, publications

Recently my paper was accepted for a conference and I presented the paper without any problem. At the final stages the publication committee is raising concerns my paper has significant plagiarism. However, the major source listed as plagiarized was my master's thesis from which I adapted my paper. So, does this count as a plagiarism since the paper was adapted from my thesis - is it a proper flag? Please let me know your thoughts!

Comment: Did you cite your thesis in the paper?

Comment: "major source'? this means you have other 'minor' sources? probably those are the main problem!

Comment: Yes, this seems like self-plagiarism. You may check with the committee if you can now cite your thesis and resolve the issue.

Comment: Most likely they didn't consider you were the plagiarised one. Self plagiarism is real but I suspect isn't the case here (unless in your field a conference paper is an important piece, like it is or it seems to me to be, in computer science. Still, I dislike self plagiarism as well. Rearrange the sentences, at least.

Answer (score 1):

No, this type of reuse is not a problem. You (with the help of your thesis advisor, most likely) should push back.

Essentially there is an exception to rules around reuse of materials between theses/dissertations and published articles or conference publications. Typically the duplication is handled via a footnote on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it very much might be self-plagiarism.
Take a look at [this text](https://ori.hhs.gov/avoiding-plagiarism-self-plagiarism-and-other-questionable-writing-practices-guide-ethical-writing), specifically the guidelines and the reasoning behind calling self-plagiarism an ethical breach. Rule of the thumb: do not *publish* the same thing twice. Reusing lectures you're giving? Sure, go ahead. Conference talks? Better not (personally, I find it completely acceptable to do that in case of "in-house" conferences adjacent to larger ones but in that case the committee is fully aware of it and is giving the green light).